# How to pass variables into an HTML body

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I have created this script that allows me to select a certain food item and the serving size and then it calculates nutritional value, adds it to a database, sums it all at the end of the day and sends me an email with an overview. It almost all works, I am just having trouble passing some variables from my script into the HTML formatted email.

In the portion of the code below, `totals` is the data values from a spreadsheet range. I expect the retrieved values of `calories`, `caloriesFromFat`, and `polyFat` to replace the matching text in the email's `htmlBody`.

```js
 var calories = totals[0][25];
    var caloriesFromFat = totals[0][26];
    var polyFat = totals[0][27];
  }
//Sends email with summary
    MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: "user@example.com",
     subject: "Daily Intake Log",
     htmlBody:  <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Calories</td>
    <td>calories</td>       

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Calories From Fat</td>
    <td>caloriesFromFat</td>        

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>PolyUnsaturated</td>
    <td>polyFat</td>        

  </tr>

</table>

   });
```

When I output the contents of the variables `calories`, `caloriesFromFat`, and `polyFat` to the log they all contain the numbers they should. But when I get the email it doesn't insert the variables' contents, just leaves the name of the variables, e.g. `calories`.

How do I get the computed values into my email?

Comment: totals is the data values of a range. When I output the contents of the variables calories, caloriesFromFat, and polyFat to the log they all contains the numbers they should. But when I try to call the variables between the table html tags in the body of the email it simply outputs "calories" instead of the data that it actually contains.

Comment: Is that what you think you're doing? That's not clear in the question - and I guess the code doesn't help, because there's no magic that will replace strings like `calories` with the content of your variable. We can fix your question first, ok?

Comment: The way you've shown htmlBody being defined can't possibly work. How are you really doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML must be a string (text), and you need to build the HTML with a text formula.   Text strings in JavaScript are put together, (concatenated) with a plus sign:

```
var tableHTML = '<table style="width:100%">' + //Note single quotes on ends
   "<tr><td>Calories</td><td>" +
   calories + 
   "</td></tr>" +
   "<tr><td>Calories From Fat</td><td>" + 
   caloriesFromFat + 
   "</td></tr>" +
   "<tr><td>PolyUnsaturated</td><td>" + 
   polyFat + 
  "</td></tr>" +
   "</table>";
```

If double quotes are used in the HTML attribute, then use single quotes on the ends of the string.
Then just use the variable name for the email HTML:

```
htmlBody: tableHTML
```

Comment: Thanks! Knew it was something simple I was missing, as usual.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this elegantly with [Printing Scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#printing_scriptlets), assuming your email HTML body is in a separate file within your project.

Here's a printing scriptlet to insert the value of `calories`. Note the syntax encloses the variable name in a special tag, `<?= ?>`:

```html
<?=calories?>
```

To fill out the template, use the HtmlService to get the template first, then treat the variables inside the printing scriptlets as object properties of the template.

```js
// get email template
var template = HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('email');

// assign values to template printing scriptlets
template.calories = totals[0][25];
template.caloriesFromFat = totals[0][26];
template.polyFat = totals[0][27];
```

### Final code

**Code.gs:**

```js
// Get my email address
var me = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

// get email template
var template = HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('email');

// assign values to template printing scriptlets
template.calories = totals[0][25];
template.caloriesFromFat = totals[0][26];
template.polyFat = totals[0][27];

// evaluate template to generate HTML
var htmlBody = template.evaluate();

//Sends email with summary
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: me,
  subject: "Daily Intake Log",
  htmlBody:  htmlBody
});
```

**email.html**

```html
<!-- HTML Email body with printing scriptlets -->
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Calories</td>
    <td><?=calories?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Calories From Fat</td>
    <td><?=caloriesFromFat?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>PolyUnsaturated</td>
    <td><?=polyFat?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```